# How can I fix "SQL03042: The ALL clause is not supported"?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, vsdb

I have just recently added our db schema into a VSTSDB project and one of the sp's is coming up with a strange error on the line:

```
revoke all from StatsReports
```

Now I've taken a look at the Sql docs for the "[revoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187719.aspx)" command and according to that it is valid sql. Also searching for the error number or text brings up nothing!

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is valid TSQL, but the error message is  - I assume - coming from VSTSDB, not from SQL Server. Running your query directly against a SQL 2008 database gives the following message:

```
The ALL permission is deprecated and maintained only for compatibility. It DOES NOT imply ALL permissions defined on the entity.
```

My guess is that VSTSDB shows an error on this syntax in order to 'remind' you to update your code. The deprecation is documented under the main page for the [REVOKE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187728%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx) command.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that depreciation message, but surely a reminder should be a warning rather than an error? Yes when denali is released it can be promoted to an error but until then...

Comment: Ok I found out why I didn't notice it! There are 2 very similar pages the one I was looking at doesn't have the depreciation message...http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187719.aspx